# How can I prevent the onmouseleave event from being triggered outside the browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a basket. When i enter the mouse, the dropdown opens and shows the items in the basket. When i leave the mouse, the dropdown closes. Inside the dropdown, i have a button for each item to remove items from the basket. When we click the button, a modal pops up, and we approve or reject. When this modal pops up, if we move the mouse away from the browser, `onMouseEnter` event is triggering and and causing the modal to close. How can i prevent this? I want the modal to close only when I click the backdrop or the reject button.

I passed `hideDropdown` function to child component(BasketItem) and tried to update `isModalShow` and `dropdown` state the same `handleClick` function. The dropdown closed, but the modal didn't pop up. How can i solve this? Can you help?

Basket component:

```
const Basket = () => {
  const [isDropdownShow, setIsDropdownShow] = useState(false);
  const { basket } = useAppContext();

  const showDropdown = (e) => {
    setIsDropdownShow(true);
  };

  const hideDropdown = (e) => {
    setIsDropdownShow(false);
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper
      onMouseEnter={showDropdown}
      onMouseLeave={hideDropdown}
      isDropdownShow={isDropdownShow}
    >
      Basket
      <span className='basket-length'>{basket.length}</span>
      {isDropdownShow && <div className='white-border'></div>}
      {basket.length === 0 && isDropdownShow && (
        <div className='dropdown empty-basket'>Basket is empty</div>
      )}
      {isDropdownShow && (
        <div className='dropdown'>
          <ul>
            {basket
              .map((basketItem, index) => {
                return (
                  <BasketItem
                    key={index}
                    basketItem={basketItem}
                    hideDropdown={hideDropdown}
                  />
                );
              })
              .sort(sortBasket)}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )}
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
export default Basket;
```

BasketItem Component:

```
const BasketItem = ({ basketItem, hideDropdown }) => {
  const [isModalShow, setIsModalShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    hideDropdown();
    setIsModalShow(true); //does not trigger
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <img src={basketItem.image} alt='product-item' />
      <div>
        <p className='basket-description'>{basketItem.description}</p>
        <span className='basket-remove' onClick={handleClick}>
          Remove
        </span>
        <Modal
          isModalShow={isModalShow}
          onClose={() => setIsModalShow(false)}
        />
      </div>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
export default BasketItem;
```

Modal:

```
const Modal = ({ isModalShow, onClose }) => {
  if (!isModalShow) return null;

  return ReactDom.createPortal(
    <>
      <Backdrop />
      <Wrapper>
        <button onClick={onClose}>CloseModal</button>
        some content
      </Wrapper>
    </>,
    document.getElementById('overlays')
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

Comment: It'd be good if you share a codesandbox link.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-buck-1lgmiu